# How do i add UIImageView to UITextView After a text

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitextview

I want to add an UIImageView to a UITextView, but i want it to be added a row after the text I already inserted in the UITextView, and i want to write after it, how can i achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using UIWebview to display HTML. That's the cleanest way to achieve what you plan to achieve as UITextView does not display pictures.

Otherwise: place your textview in a cell inside a UITableView, then add a cell which contains a UIImageView after the first cell, and take care to set Tableview cell separator to none. But you'll need to adapt the first cell size to the text size. That is going to be more complex, with little or no advantage.

Comment: im trying to do it with UIWebView, but how do i link img src="X" to a local path? im trying "cards/5.png" but it doesn't work

Comment: If you are using "defaults" (i.e.: not adding Folder References, btw there is an option for HTML folders), your filesystem is FLAT. That is to say that your app will see a single directory, with everything in the same flat "folder". So your cards/5.png will be stored as "5.png" .
Instead, If you add HTML folders to your project (CREATE FOLDER REFERENCES), files and folders will be copied with their structure intact when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking something like this!

```
// Text box

searchText =[[UITextField alloc]init];
searchText.frame = CGRectMake(20, 80, appDelegate.wVal-40, 30);
searchText.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
searchText.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
searchText.layer.borderWidth= 2;
searchText.delegate = self;
[searchText addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

//Adding Padding

UIView *searchtextpad =[[UIView alloc]init];
searchtextpad.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, searchText.frame.size.height);

//Adding Image

UIImageView *searchImage = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
searchImage.frame = CGRectMake(searchtextpad.frame.origin.x+5, searchtextpad.frame.origin.y+5, searchtextpad.frame.size.width-10, searchtextpad.frame.size.height-10);
searchImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"search.png"];
[searchtextpad addSubview:searchImage];
searchText.leftView = searchtextpad;
searchText.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Like this you can add to your text view.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Sorry ! New to IOS! I dont know swift coding now ! GOnna learn it.